# Sort python list with order of another, larger list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have 2 lists, for example:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
b = ['c','a','dog']
```

I would like to sort the common elements in list b by the order of list a, to get something like this:

```
['a','c','dog']
```

I have read similar questions using `sorted()`, however I cannot make it work when the lists do not contain the same elements (i.e. `'dog'` in list `b`).

Comment: Can't you just filter list `a` using `b` and then sort it?

Comment: Can you provide an example where the sorted list is not simply sorted by lexicographical order? Because it’s not really obvious what role `a` plays when it’s just sorted naturally like that.

Comment: It's not clear what behavior you want it to have when 'dog' isn't in list a.

Comment: What do you want to get if it's `['c', 'eagle', 'a','dog']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd turn `a` into dictionary:

```
a_dict = dict((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(a))
```

and use `float('inf')` to indicate values to be sorted at the end:

```
sorted(b, key=lambda v: a_dict.get(v, float('inf')))
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> b = ['c','a','dog']
>>> a_dict = dict((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(a))
>>> sorted(b, key=lambda v: a_dict.get(v, float('inf')))
['a', 'c', 'dog']
```

This has the advantage of speed; `dict` lookups are O(1) versus list `.index()` lookups having a `O(n)` cost. You'll notice this more as `a` and `b` grow in size.

The disadvantage is that duplicate values in `a` are handled differently; the `dict` approach picks the last index versus `.index()` picking the first.

Comment: That disadvantage isn't really much of one as the list can be processed once (no big shakes as one is saving on the lookup) by using `dict( (v, i) for i, v in enumerate(OrderedDict.fromkeys(a)) )` instead...

Comment: I was thinking using `reversed()` could solve the 'problem' here, actually. :-) But an `OrderedDict` could well be faster in that case, as reversing `enumerate()` would require materializing the enumeration in memory..

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> b = ['c','a','dog']
>>> def func(x):
...     try:
...         return a.index(x)
...     except ValueError:
...         return float("inf")
...     
>>> sorted(b, key = func)
['a', 'c', 'dog']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use (frozen) sets. I have not timed this against other answers.

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> b = ['c','a','dog']
>>> list((frozenset(a)^frozenset(b))^frozenset(a))
['a', 'c', 'dog']
```

Comment: Python sets are unordered collections. This works when I test it but will this solution work all the time?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `bisect`

```
import bisect
from operator import itemgetter
a = ['a','b','c','d','e']
b = ['c','a','dog']
l = sorted([(x, bisect.bisect(a, x)) for x in b], key=itemgetter(1))
l = [x[0] for x in l]
print l
['a', 'c', 'dog']
```